# How to read and write special characters, in xml, android

Tags: android

Hi I have created xml where i need to pass file name and sent to server. It is working fine. But when the file name contains special character the name looks different in xml. similarly in reading same problem occurred. eg if file name is ♥♣◘• then i cant send the exact in xml also i cant read as it is from xml. How to resolve this type of issue. Whether i need to set any parameters in xml?

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have en ENCODING problem... Try out a few like UTF16 or UTF32... I know there are some issues in Android 'bout encoding stuff, you never really know what you get except if you FORCE it !

Try then using stuffs like :

```
String(byte[] data, String charsetName)
Converts the byte array to a string using the named charset.
```

with charsetname such as "UTF-8" or "UTF-16".

Comment: I agree its an encoding problem. The xml should be marked with an encoding header if its anything other than ASCII. For example: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Comment: I have mentioned <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: When you encode or decode are you forcing it to use utf-8. Are the "special characters" legal utf-8 characters?

Comment: Marking it in the XML file as :
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Isn't enough... You have to specify it in your code

Comment: Could you paste a bit of code like, what are you using to parse you XML file ?